# Trying to crop tiff images with python script

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I am using a [script](https://github.com/danvk/oldnyc/blob/master/ocr/tess/crop_morphology.py) from github to crop images leaving only text blocks.
I am trying to keep my images as tiff files for the highest quality possible because I will be doing OCR.

Now the problem that I have is it only works with jpg -> png, if I change the values to tiff at the end of the string I get an error like this

```
newOCR10.tiff image has wrong mode
```

Any Ideas on how I could solve this problem?

Here is the code that I change:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and '*' in sys.argv[1]:
        files = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])
        random.shuffle(files)
    else:
        files = sys.argv[1:]

    for path in files:
        out_path = path.replace('.jpg', '.crop.png') //'.tiff' '.crop.tiff'
        if os.path.exists(out_path): continue
        try:
            process_image(path, out_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print '%s %s' % (path, e)
```

tiffinfo newOCR6.tiff returns me this info:

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0xca90b8 (13275320)
  Image Width: 2316 Image Length: 2866
  Resolution: 300, 300 (unitless)
  Bits/Sample: 16
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  FillOrder: msb-to-lsb
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 1
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Page Number: 0-1
  White Point: 0.3127-0.329
  PrimaryChromaticities: 0.640000,0.330000,0.300000,0.600000,0.150000,0.060000
```

Comment: Check/upgrade your tiff conversion library and try again.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: At least in Linux you have to compile/install correct version of libtiff (or other tiff-library). Sometimes the default one is not compatible with used OpenCV version.  Hereäs example with OpenCV 3.4.1 https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

Comment: I updated opencv but I get the same error still

Comment: Check the mode of your TIFF file - either with `tiffinfo`, `tifftags` or ImageMagick `identify -verbose yourImage.tif`. Some Python libraries have difficulty with 16-bit TIFFs.

Comment: I added additional information from tiffinfo

Comment: Mmm... a 16-bit greyscale image. Can you track which line generates the error? Also, the image you tested doesn't appear to be the one in the error message...